# How to get rid of a specific div tag when scraping using Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

The tag structure is like below.

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  Text...
</div>
```

I would like to get class a div excluding class b and c divs.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the xml with [etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and using an [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) expression to select the text nodes you want may be the best solution here, combined with some Python string manipulation as needed. Demonstrating in iPython:

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: str = '''<div class="a">
   ...:   <div class="b">Unwanted</div>
   ...:   <div class="c">Unwanted</div>
   ...:   Text...
   ...: </div>'''

In [3]: root = etree.fromstring(str)

In [4]: root.xpath("//div[@class='a']/text()")
Out[4]: ['\n  ', '\n  ', '\n  Text...\n']

In [5]: ''.join(root.xpath("//div[@class='a']/text()")).strip()
Out[5]: 'Text...'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use soup.find for this:

```
filtered_divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "a"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it only scrape text below nested classes b, c divs without whatever inside class b and c?

Comment: I have not tried it. Could you check it for yourself?